# Django filter the model on ManyToMany count?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Suppose I have something like this in my models.py:

```
class Hipster(models.Model):
  name = CharField(max_length=50)

class Party(models.Model):
  organiser = models.ForeignKey()
  participants = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name="participants")
```

Now in my views.py I would like to do a query which would fetch a party for the user where there are more than 0 participants.

Something like this maybe:

```
user = Hipster.get(pk=1) 
hip_parties = Party.objects.filter(organiser=user, len(participants) > 0)
```

What's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

If this works this is how I would do it.

Best way can mean a lot of things: best performance, most maintainable, etc.  Therefore I will not say this is the best way, but I like to stick to the ORM features as much as possible since it seems more maintainable.

```
from django.db.models import Count

user = Hipster.objects.get(pk=1) 
hip_parties = (Party.objects.annotate(num_participants=Count('participants'))
                            .filter(organiser=user, num_participants__gt=0))
```

Comment: This is another good way to do it, albeit not as succinct as the chosen answer.

Comment: +1, "more than Y", "less than X" are all covered here, not just null which actually answers the question, "Django filter the model on ManyToMany count"

Comment: This answers the OPs summarised question better than the accepted answer, not just for the case where you want to filter on zero related instances.

Comment: @gregoltsov 5 years later, this _is_ now the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 38):

```
Party.objects.filter(organizer=user, participants__isnull=False)
Party.objects.filter(organizer=user, participants=None)
```

Comment: I don't think this is the most elegant of solutions, but it works in my case. I will still look around if there's any sane way of doing it.

Comment: What's not elegant about this solution? It's exactly what you asked for! :) It's not entirely clear from the answer, but you would use one or the other, not both. Two approaches to the same problem.

Comment: More elegant would of course be if one could refer to the number directly. null is not the same as len() == 0, or am I missing something?

Comment: This is the case where I actually might prefer pure SQL statement.

Comment: @Ska But that is exactly what my solution does. It allows you specify the actual numeric value.

Comment: @solartic Yes I know, but I just don't like the way Django handles that and will refrain from using it until I absolutely have to. Yuji's solution solved my problem in the simple way and this is what I needed. I'd much rather have an API similar to what I posted in the question.

Comment: @Yuji, When i do this, "participants__isnull=False" will cause duplicated entries. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @solartic, how does it allow you to specify an actual numeric value? For example, what if I want a query that shows me all parties with more than two participants?

Comment: @tufelkinder See my example below. Just change num_participants__gt=0 to num_participants__gt=1 or num_participants__gte=2.

Comment: @solartic, I saw your example below, and upvoted it. It seems like the better answer.

Comment: @crossin if a query can result in duplicates, append `.distinct()` to your query.

Answer (score 6):

Easier with `exclude`:

```
# organized by user and has more than 0 participants
Party.objects.filter(organizer=user).exclude(participants=None)
```

Also returns distinct results

Answer (score 5):

Derived from @Yuji-'Tomita'-Tomita answer, I've also added .distinct('id') to exclude the duplitate records:

```
Party.objects.filter(organizer=user, participants__isnull=False).distinct('id')
```

Therefore, each party is listed only once.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method when trying to return a queryset having at least one object in a manytomany field:
First, return all the possible manytomany objects:

```
profiles = Profile.objects.all()
```

Next, filter the model by returning only the queryset containing at least one of the profiles:

```
hid_parties = Party.objects.filter(profiles__in=profiles)
```

To do the above in a single line:

```
hid_parties = Party.objects.filter(profiles__in=Profile.objects.all())
```

You can further refine individual querysets the normal way for more specific filtering.
**NOTE**:This may not be the most effective way, but at least it works for me.