# Count attributes of many to many relation and filter by it

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to do something slightly different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883916/django-filter-the-model-on-manytomany-count).

Suppose I have something like this in my models.py:

```
class Hipster(models.Model):
  name = CharField(max_length=50)
  has_iphone = BooleanField(default=True)

class Party(models.Model):
  participants = models.ManyToManyField(Hipster, related_name="participants")
```

And then do:

```
hip_parties = Party.objects.filter(participants__has_iphone__istrue__count=4)
```

How can I do that?

UPDATE:

```
>>> Question.objects.filter(options__is_correct=True).annotate(options__count=Count('options')).filter(options__count=0)
[]
>>> q = Question.objects.get(id=49835)
>>> q.options.all()[0].is_correct
False
>>> q.options.all()[1].is_correct
False
>>> q.options.all()[2].is_correct
False
>>> q.options.all()[3].is_correct
False
>>> q.options.all()[4].is_correct
False
>>> q.options.all()[5].is_correct
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/patrickbassut/Programming/logus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 177, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: you can simply use count like Party.objects.filter(participants__has_iphone).count() and then you can do your rest of the logic

Comment: I don't think that's going to work.

Comment: You are having many to many relation to Profile. Does Profile has has_iphone field ?

Comment: Sorry, just corrected that. It was meant to be ```Hipster```.

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotations for this.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Party.objects.filter(
    participants__has_iphone=True
).annotate(iphone_count=Count('participants')).filter(
    iphone_count=4
)
```

Comment: Aren't you only filtering the parties that have at least one Hipster with an iPhone? I mean, if the only ones left in participants would be the ones that are true, that would be great. But I guess it's not the case.

Comment: Yes, but isn't that what you want? You want parties where there are 4 hipsters with iphones. So filtering out parties with no hipsters with iphones is the right behaviour.

Comment: The query above gets all Parties that have at least one true. I want the ones that have exactly 4 true. You can even remove your first filter and it will make no difference.

Comment: No, that's not true at all. See the docs on [order of annotate and filter clauses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) - the first filter restricts the annotation to participants who have iphones, the annotation counts those participants, and the second filter restricts the whole thing to parties where there are four iphone-wielding hipsters.

Comment: I tested here, and you're right. I had this impression because even though I filter only the ones that have 4 hipsters with iphone, it still shows the ones that doesn't on the manytomany. But that's totally right. I wouldn't need to open that question then. Thanks a lot for opening my eyes on that.

Comment: I edited my answer with the output from the terminal.