# Django groupby on manyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

```
class Model1():
    name = models.charField()  # this field has only 4 choices, so only 4 entries would be there

class model2():
    field1 = models.charfield()
    field2 = model.ManytoManyField(Model1, related_name="model2")
```

now What I want to do is query on model2 (on field2) and group by model2 results on the basis of this field.

assume 4 values in model1 are `A, B, C, D`. 
so when I query on model2 i should be able to get results grouped by `A, B, C, D`.   something like below

```
[
  {
     "name": "A",
     "field1": []
  },
  {
     "name": "B",
     "field1": []
  },
  ...
]
```

assuming we are using postgresql so we can use `extra = {}` parameter in query.  till now I'm using `itertools groupby` by thats not very efficient. looking for orm query if possible otherwise raw query.

See attached image for reference

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIxfZ.jpg)

Comment: How group if `field2` has two or more values?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev see attached image.

Comment: If you are using postgresql then why not you are using Arrayfield ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django filter the model on ManyToMany count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883916/django-filter-the-model-on-manytomany-count)

Comment: It seems even simpler than the question that is duplicated.