# Django filter the model on ManyToMany count with a limit specific to each object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

[Django filter the model on ManyToMany count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883916/django-filter-the-model-on-manytomany-count)

My question is very similar to the above one, but with a difference: there's a limit to the many-to-many relationship inside the model.

So instead of being

```
class Party(models.Model):
    organiser = models.ForeignKey()
    participants = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', 
        related_name="participants")
```

It would be

```
class Party(models.Model):
    organiser = models.ForeignKey()
    max_participants = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    participants = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', 
        related_name="participants")
```

So I want to find all Party objects in which the count of participants is less than `Party.max_participants`. How can I make that query using Django's ORM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we annotate every `Party` object with the number of participants, then we perform a `.filter(..)` where `max_participants` is greater than (`__gt`) then number of participants:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F

Party.objects.annotate(
    num_participants=Count('participants')
).filter(
    max_participants__gt=F('num_participants')
)
```

So the [**`F(..)`-expression**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) is used here to refer to the `num_participants` annotation we have defined, and as constraint we thus add that the `max_participants` column is greater than that number.